# XmlIgnore on a property inside a list

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization, xmlserializer, xmlignore

How do I ignore the property which is in a type within a list of another type which I am trying to serialize?

```
        public string SerializeTag(List<Tag> reservedTags)
    {
        string timestampFilenamePrefix = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        string filename = string.Format("ReservedTags_{0}.xml", timestampFilenamePrefix);
        using (var stream = File.Create(filename))
        {
            var objectToBeSerialized = new CompanyDemoData();
            objectToBeSerialized.TagsReserved = reservedTags;

            var namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            namespaces.Add("", "");

            XmlAttributeOverrides xOver = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
            XmlAttributes attrs = new XmlAttributes();
            attrs.XmlIgnore = true;
            xOver.Add(typeof(Tag), "GUID", attrs);

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CompanyDemoData), xOver);
            serializer.Serialize(XmlWriter.Create(stream), objectToBeSerialized, namespaces);

            stream.Flush();
            return filename;
        }
    }
```

```
{
    [XmlRoot("CompanyDemoData")]
    public class CompanyDemoData
    {
        [XmlElement("Tag")]
        public List<Tag> TagsReserved { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
namespace Demo.Model
{
    public class Tag
    {
        [XmlElement("TagId")]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("GUID")]
        public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am trying to avoid the GUID property to be serialized under certain situations. So I don't want to set the XmlIgnore attribute directly in the Tag class. And I don't want to use the nullable wrapper for GUID.

I think the error is that I am creating a serializer for the type CompanyDemoData which doesn't contain the property which I am trying to set the override attribute.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note: using XmlAttributeOverrides should usually be discouraged, or at the very least it requires you to cache and reuse the serializer instance. Otherwise it will leak memory like a sieve. Have you tried using conditional serialization? Meaning: adding a `public bool ShouldSerializeGuid()` method that returns true or false as appropriate? (This is a pattern recognized by many APIs)

Comment: thanks for the information. didn't know that it was discouraged. will consider conditional serialization in the future.

Comment: The problem is that it generates an assembly *per serializer instance* when using that setup; it can be used, but you'll need to cache and reuse the instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error here is in the argument `member string` in `xOver.Add(typeof(Tag), "GUID", attrs)`.

You are passing the `XMLElement Name` not the `Member Name` which is "Guid" not "GUID".

The line should be `xOver.Add(typeof(Tag), "Guid", attrs)`.

I've tested it and it works. Hope it does for you!